# How to retrieve 2 values from different cells and format them in a different cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

In A13 I want to display:

Team1 vs. Team2

where Team1 would be the content from cell B5 and Team2 the content from cell B6...

How can I achieve that?

In the picture you can see my attemp to do that: =B5 vs. =B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one equals sign in a formula.

Do either what @Ondkloss answered, or this:
`=B5 & " vs." & B6`

If you want to be really hardcore and have a formula you can drag down for all 4 cells, try this. Paste this to cells A12 through A15: 
`=INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+3) & " vs. " & INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+4)`

To show "EE5 winner" change the above to this instead:
`=IF(INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+3)="","EE" & (ROW()-12)*2+1 & " Winner",INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+3)) & " vs. " & IF(INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+4)="","EE" & (ROW()-12)*2+2 & " Winner",INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-12)*2+4))`

Comment: wow, thank you! how can I edit it to put (EE5 Winner) If the field where this winner was supposed to be is still empty?

Comment: See edits. It makes function out of the row the formula is in so it looks in cells relative to that. The EE# will now fill in similarly. INDIRECT is the most powerful tool in Excel.

Comment: thanks for the edit... and for the advice also! I don't use excel for such purposes too much.. I joined a pool and found some bugs in the spreadsheet so I tried to fix it myself but I basically changed the existent formulas, never added one before

Answer (score 1):

[`=CONCATENATE(B5, " vs. ", B6)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010342288.aspx) to join multiple text strings into one.

Comment: Thank you! However, here I had to use ; instead of , ... If you could edit that it would help others better.. I can't edit just those 2 chars, it says I must edit at least 6 chars

Comment: It's a regional thing (from what I've understood). I actually have to use semicolon myself, but most formulas online use colon, as you can see from the API I linked.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it was a link, I just pasted the syntax... I saw  the page now, thanks for the clarification!